what if we don't write answer in the q/a test and just pass questions will RAG generate response?
I'm working on KG-RAG integration and LLM enhancement. I'm using Q/A test dataset to generate the output results.
My results are based on:
Question,
Expected Answer (which I'm giving in the dataset),
Predicted answer,
GPT answer.
Now, what if I don't give expected answer in the dataset. Will RAG and GPT be able to generate responses and will I be able to evaluate the performance metrics???
I need an idea to execute it and calculate the final results.

Please provide code snippets with what you already did.
